# On the shift in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning "on the shift" in this context?

*The Climate Group works with business and governments **on the shift**  to a low carbon economy, and Kenber issued a stark warning on the choice for the world between a high carbon and low carbon future.*

Comment: Since the word "shift" is confusing you here, I imagine the first thing you did was look it up in a dictionary. What did you find there? After looking it up and learning all the relevant definitions for the word, what's still confusing you about it?

Comment: The group works with the government on a task. This task is the shift to a low carbon economy.

Comment: I perceived it like Climate Group with business and government works in specific way "on the shift" interchangeably to a low carbon economy. Though I have seen all possible meanings in dictionary I wanted to be sure meaning in this very context. I don't know why I attributed it to the description of the way they worked, but not as switching high carbon economy to low carbon economy. I needed to think little bit more. I have this kind of contextual misunderstandings as English is not my native language. Thanks Ian for simplification.

Comment: "on the shift" => "on the topic/problem of shifting"

Answer (score -1):

***On the shift***, refers to a general shift (move) in the economy to a low-carbon future.

Another way of saying it would be to replace those words with: ***as part of the general change to***.